# Constructor Injection together with JDA and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, dao, discord-jda

I am struggling with initializing JDA as the "addEventListeners" requires me to input the EventListeners.. However, my EventListeners have "injected constructors" (if that's the correct word) that is grabbing my Dao's.

I would gladly use @Autowire in my EventListeners, but it keeps on giving me a NullPointer.

I think the issue is that JDA extends their EventListener, which basically loads outside of Spring Boot, even though I've added the @Service annotation on the Listener.

You can see my problem below at:
.addEventListeners(new JDAEventListener())

Obviously, I am not able to do `new JDAEventListener()`as it requires the WixSubscriptionDao. However, I am not able to understand how to initiate the JDAEventListener without WixSubscriptionDao, as I need the Dao for further data handling.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, LoginException {

    JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
            .setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL)
            .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
            .addEventListeners(new JDAEventListener())
            .build();
    DISCORD_CONSTANT.jda = jda.awaitReady();
    setupDefault();
}
```

```
@Service
public class JDAEventListener implements EventListener {

    private final WixSubscriptionDao wixSubscriptionDao;

    public JDAEventListener(WixSubscriptionDao wixSubscriptionDao) {
        this.wixSubscriptionDao = wixSubscriptionDao;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(@NotNull GenericEvent genericEvent) {
        if (genericEvent instanceof ReadyEvent) {
            System.out.println("ReadyEvent done");
            ArrayList<WixSubscription> wixSubscriptions = wixSubscriptionDao.findAll();
            System.out.println(wixSubscriptions.size());
    }
}
```

I would love to do this, but as wrote above, the @Autowired Dao is giving me a NullPointer, even though it's defined in the SpringConfig. (The DAO works perfectly when using the constructor method)

```
@Service
public class JDAEventListener implements EventListener {

    @Autowired
    private WixSubscriptionDao wixSubscriptionDao;

    public JDAEventListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(@NotNull GenericEvent genericEvent) {
        if (genericEvent instanceof ReadyEvent) {
            System.out.println("ReadyEvent done");
            ArrayList<WixSubscription> wixSubscriptions = wixSubscriptionDao.findAll();
            System.out.println(wixSubscriptions.size());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you create class annotated with `@Component` which implements `CommandLineRunner` interface. This means that, the `run` method will be executed when the application starts. Also, you can inject other Spring beans into it, like for example `JDAEventListener` beans.

```
@Component
public class JDAInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final JDAEventListener jdaEventListener;
    
    // Constructor injection
    public JDAInitializer(JDAEventListener jdaEventListener) {
        this.jdaEventListener = jdaEventListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
                .setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL)
                .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL)
                .addEventListeners(jdaEventListener)
                .build();
        DISCORD_CONSTANT.jda = jda.awaitReady();
        setupDefault();
    }

 ...
}
```